# XMPP: Allowing clients to communicate through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, chat, xmpp

So I'm working on this site web app that should let users **easily** chat with untrusted other members if they want to *with their own software like Goog Chat, Facebook, etc* (not the central feature though).

So to combine "easily" and "their own client" with "untrusted," I envision a feature like so:
1. Bob wants to chat with Alice.  Both have XMPP clients.
2. Bob clicks on Alice.
3. My site sets up an XMPP "relay"/"proxy" through which Bob and Alice can gets each others' messages, but their XMPP identities are never revealed to the other -- only my sites "proxy" XMPP indentity.

```
Bob <-> ProxyThatHidesIdentities <-> Alice
```

Is there a good mechanism for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like regular [XMPP Multi User Chat](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) (MUC), but in this particular case you're just restricting rooms to a maximum two participants.

With MUC, chat rooms can be fully anonymous; people just choose (or you enforce) aliases and so the XMPP addresses appear to each user as `some-chat-room@chat.example.com/bob`, where `example.com` is *your* server.  Neither party's origin XMPP ID appears to others.

However, this would require each party to have a client that supports MUC.  Most do, but whether the native Google Talk client does, I have no idea.

I'd also note that Facebook users currently cannot talk to anyone outside the Facebook network via XMPP (or any other means).